# Arrows plugin returning Python error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error

I'm trying to run the Arrows plugin on QGIS 2.10 (Win 8.1), but I'm getting an error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/.../.qgis2/python/plugins\arrows\arrows.py", line 79, in run_set
>       self.draw_arrows()   File "C:/U.../.qgis2/python/plugins\arrows\arrows.py", line 128, in
>   draw_arrows
>       width = attributes[self.conf["arrow_width_field"]] * float(unicode(self.conf["arrow_width_factor"])) TypeError: unsupported
>   operand type(s) for *: 'QPyNullVariant' and 'float'

Can anyone help me out with this? What is going wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: By the error msg, it sounds like a data field type issue (not existing or wrong data type).  When are you receiving this error, when you load it, when you run it?

Comment: The error occurs when I run the plugin, after selecting the several parameters needed - I've never used this specific plugin before, but I followed as closely as possible the example given by the plugin author.
I am not versed in Python programming, so I neeed some really simple explanation of what is the problem and how can I  work around it.

Comment: Anyone else has some input on this problem?